# Difference between myClassInstance.property and myClassInsance.getProperty()?

Tags: java, setter, getter

Iam a Java beginner and i would like to ask whats the pros and cons about this:

If i make a Class and i wont write my own setters and getters i can just get and set my class's properties like:

```
myClassInstance.name = "Jones"
myClassInstance.job = "Manager"

System.out.println(myClassInstance.name);
System.out.println(myClassInstance.job);
```

Why better if i make getters and setters and do like this:

```
myClassInstance.setName("Jones");
myClassInstance.setJob("Manager");

System.out.println(myClassInstance.getName());
System.out.println(myClassInstance.getJob());
```

Comment: If you like the property-style without getters and setters have a look at **groovy** since it generates these for you. If you have a clean code-style/rule than the encapsulation thing is not a problem in reality as all dynamic languages show. But of course this is a question of taste.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is related to one of the basic principals of OO design: Encapsulation!

Accessors (also known as getters and setters) are methods that let you read and write the value of an instance variable of an object

```
public class AccessorExample {
private String attribute;

public String getAttribute() {
 return attribute;
}

public void setAttribute(String attribute) {
 this.attribute = attribute;
}
}
```

Why to use them?

Getter and Setters make APIs more stable. Lets consider a field public in a class which is accessed by other classes. Now later on, you want to add any extra logic while getting and setting the variable. This will impact the existing client that uses the API. So any changes to this public field will require change to each class that refers it. On the contrary, with accessor methods, one can easily add some logic like cache some data, lazily initialize it later. Moreover, one can fire a property changed event if the new value is different from the previous value. All this will be seamless to the class that gets value using accessor method.

Also Getters and setters methods allow different access levels - for eg. Get may be public, but the Set could be protected.

Answer (score 2):

directly accessing the fields will lead to voilation of [encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29).

making public variables to access them will be difficult to manage the state of that object.
where as with methods you can easily control state of the object.

Comment: Well im not really understeand becouse my english is not to good but thanks anyway. So i have to use the getters and setters right ?

Answer (score 2):

Using getters and setters instead of public members is called encapsulation, and is a fundamental OOP concept. This way you are able to control the input and keep some sort of logic and validity to your models.

```
class Bottle {
    public int volume = 0;
}

class EncapsulatedBottle {
    private int volume = 0;

    public void setVolume(int volume) throws Exception {
        if (volume < 1) {
            throw new Exception("A bottle cannot have a negative volume");
        }
        this.volume = volume;
    }
    public int getVolume() {
        return this.volume;
    }
}
```

Spot the difference :-)

Answer (score 1):

Using getters and setters gives you more control over the validity of your objects, giving you the option of testing values that are set to ensure that they are reasonable, etc. (And of course, for read-only properties, you just leave off the setter.) On a modern JVM with a just-in-time compiler, they essentially don't cost anything; if they're really just reading and writing to a private data member, and if they're in a hotspot (bit of code that gets used a  **lot**), the JIT will inline them.

Answer (score 1):

Using getters/setters is normally better, because:

- you can restrict (public) access to readonly (no setter)
- you can add additional code without having to recompile/change the users of the property (i.e. classes that call the getter/setter)
- it complies with the Java Bean specification which states a property *must* have getters/setters - and many libraries/frameworks, like Java EL etc. rely on that contract